# How to pass time token on an eval for Splunk Dashboard

Tags: time, token, splunk

Need some help with learning how to set a token for time in a dashboard in eval that will populate the date user selects. I have set my time token already and would like to pass my time token to | eval EndingSpiral=strpTime("$tokEarliest$", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), but the dates are not populating. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or not doing? I would appreciate your help.

```
 This is how I set my time token earlier in the xml code:

<fieldset submitButton="false">
    <input type="time" token="time_range" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Select Time Range</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-7d@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
      <change>
      </change>
    </input>

<query>
| eval EndingSpiral=strpTime("$tokEarliest$", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), Spiraling= strpTime(relevantSprialTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q")
|  eval Start = strptime(SomeTime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q"), End=strptime(SomeOtherTime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N")



<earliest>$time_range.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$time_range.latest$</latest><progress>
      <eval token="tokEarliest">strptime($time_range.earliest$,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")</eval>
      <eval token="tokLatest">strptime($time_range.latest$,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")</eval>
    </progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Time tokens are not strings so they shouldn't be used as arguments to `strptime`.  It also does not make sense to parse the result of `strptime`.  You'll get a null result in each case.  Just assign `$time_range.earliest$` to EndingSpiral.

Comment: Tokens *are* strings - and you *can* reference them in function like `strptime`

Comment: I stand corrected.  I hadn't used time tokens within a query so I assumed they were in epoch form.  A quick test shows they are indeed strings, but still can't be used in `strptime` because they aren't timestamps.  I was able to use `relative_time(now(), $time_range.earliest|s")` to convert the token to an epoch timestamp.

Comment: Make that `relative_time(now(), $time_range.earliest|s$)`.